# How to select multipule photos in IOS native photo picker called from Qt QFileDialog

Tags: ios, qt

I am trying to select multiple photos from photo library in IOS,below code is suggested by QT to call native photo selector but as soon as i select first photo the photo selector closes and i have the file name and directory to that single file.
Now i am wondering how can i select multiple photos in same native ios photo selector and access their directories in `dialog.selectedFiles()`

```
const QStringList picturesLocations =QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::PicturesLocation);
QFileDialog dialog(this, tr("Open File"));
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
dialog.setDirectory( picturesLocations.last());
dialog.exec();
qDebug() << "Selected Pictures " <<dialog.selectedFiles().first();
```